# Alternating colors in table in jsp using CSS

Tags: html, css, jsp, dynamic, html-table

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to alternate HTML table row colors using JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241897/how-to-alternate-html-table-row-colors-using-jsp)
>   [Table row - Giving alternate colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995684/table-row-giving-alternate-colors)

Can anyone provide basic code for dynamically adding rows in a table with alternate colors using CSS in jsp file kindly provide this code?

Comment: have you tried to [search for your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+alternating+row+color)?

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<?
    boolean evenRow = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRowsToDisplay; i++)
    {
?>

<tr class="<?= evenRow? "evenrowstyle" : "oddrowstyle" ?>"><td>whatever</td></tr>

<?
        evenRow = !evenRow;
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks riley for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two options:

- either you have to add a style class to all even (or odd) rows in your jsp
- or you can do it dynamically on the client with javascript (if that's an option)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [CSS odd and even selectors](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.html).

Comment: Do browsers support that? IE specifically?

Comment: It's officially CSS 3 I believe so not before IE9, the alternative is to look at jQuery.com as that includes a css selector that does support these constructs and would allow you to create the alternating effect you are looking for.

Comment: answering my own question: No they don't. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38

Comment: @seanizer - True but hey, IE might not be a consideration for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

as in

```
<style>
#TableID tr:nt-child(odd){
background-color:white;
}

#TableID tr:nth-child(even){
background-color:silver;
}
</style>
```

Comment: fails in several browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38